# is it possible to achieve operator overloads resolution with priority?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++20, overload-resolution

The code below fails to compile because both overloads of the `operator<<` are good candidates for the pair of types `StremWrap, A`, and the compiler cannot choose one of them.

I would like that the overload on `StreamWrap` is used only as a last resource, i.e. only if no other overload matches. In the simplistic example below, I can achieve that by uncommenting the constraint which disable the overload of the object is of type `A`.

Obviously this is not a scalable solution, if I have a multitude of types for which an alternative overload that matches exists. I am thinking to make all objects for which an alternative overload exist to inherit from some dummy struct `struct B{}`, then use `is_base_of<B,T>` as a constraint to decide when to disable the first overload.

However I wonder if a more generic and less intrusive solution exist.

**EDIT**
To be clear, I want to know if there is a way to disable the first overload if an alternative overload exists, i.e., in pseudocode, `requires( no other overload of operator<< for (StreamWrap, T) exists)`

```
struct StreamWrap
{
};

struct A
{
    int x, y;
};

template <typename T>
    //requires (!is_same_v<T,A>) // uncommenting this works
StreamWrap& operator<<(StreamWrap& os, const T& v)
{
    std::cout << v;
    return os;
}

template <typename OS>
OS& operator<<(OS& os, const A& v)
{
    os << v.x << ' ' << v.y;
    return os;
}

void foo()
{
    A a{ 1,2 };
    StreamWrap w{};
    w << a << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The priority of individual priorities is not configurable in C++. They are what they are.

Comment: Add a specific `operator<<(StreamWrap& os, A const& v)`, which will be higher rank than either of the two templates.

Comment: Do you need both of them to be templates? Changing the first one to `StreamWrap& operator<<(StreamWrap& os, const A& v)` or the second one to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& v)` would make it unambiguous.

Comment: @Kevin, @Eljay, I need both of them to be templates. I have multiple streamers `StreamWrap1`, `StreamWrap2`, etc.. which targets different devices requiring different formats. I also have multiple classes `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, etc...

Comment: @Drew Dormann, retagged as C++20

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, I am not trying to reinvent C++. I want to know if there is a way to write the constraint on the first overload to exclude all cases where an alternative overload exists.

Comment: Can you use C++20, or do you have to use C++17?  If you have to use C++17, you can write the "requires" in old (and awkward, in comparison to C++20) C++17 style.

Comment: @Eljay, yes I can use C++20

Comment: This is just a different way of phrasing "use priorities for overloads". And. like I already mentioned, C++ operator overloads have fixed priorities. They are what they are, the answer is the same no matter how the question is phrased.